# How to access and modify list anywhere within a definition?

Tags: python, list, parameters

**Context of my problem**

I'm trying to access a so called "master list" which is inside `def parent_function()` and I want to edit/modify/manipulate the list with two functions I've created `function_one()`, which searches for a specific guest, and `function_two()`,which adds a new guest, but I'm running into a little problem where the `parent_function()` takes in the following parameter: `guest, age, gender, guest_tag, user_option` but in `function_one()` it only contains `user_option` and for `function_two()` only `guest, age, gender, guest_tag`.

**The actual problem**

When I call for `function_one()` and try to input `user_option`, I get the following error:

`TypeError: parent_function() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'age', 'gender', 'guest_tag', and 'user_option'`

**My code:**

```
def parent_function(guest, age, gender, guest_tag, user_option):
    guestlist = [
            ["Joe", 20, "Male", "J20M-1"],
            ["Larry", 53, "Male", "L53M-1"],
            ["Alice", 32, "Female", "A32F-1"],
            ["Marry", 41, "Female", "M41F-1"]
            ]
    booklist = [guest, age, gender, guest_tag]
   
    for i in guestlist: 
        if i[0] == booklist[0]:
            print("Guest Tag already exists!")
            break
        else:
            guestlist.append(booklist)
            print("Guest has been added to booklist.")
            print(guestlist)
            break

    if "?" in user_option:
        for i in range(len(guestlist)):
            if guestlist[i][0].split() == user_option[:-1]:
                print(guestlist[i][1])



#search for a guest
def function_one():
    user_option = input("Choose a function> ")
    parent_function(user_option)


#Add new guest
def function_two():
    guest = input("Input name> ")
    age = 17
    gender = "Male"
    guest_tag = "EXEPTED"
    parent_function(guest, age, gender, guest_tag)


def main():
    print("1 - Function one\n2 - Function two\n3 - Function three")
    user_option = input("Choose a function> ")
    if user_option == "1":
        function_one()
    elif user_option == "2":
        function_two()
    elif user_option == "3":
        parent_function()
main()
```

**Expected output**

I want the a way to manipulate my list, `guestlist` globally, without using the global variable.
In other words, I want to edit the list anywhere in the program so that when I add a new guest I can view the new guest list with the modification.

Comment: Have you tried making a class to keep track of guests? It wouldn't be global like you want and you can have the methods inside the class that will manipulate the state of your guest list.

Comment: This would be a good example of when to create a class, with methods that read and/or update a subset of the instance attributes.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the functions only *add* or *remove* items in the list, and don't *reassign* the list completely, then you don't need the `global` keyword at all (although the list will still be a global variable).

You don't need to pass the list as an argument to the functions.  They can access the list directly.

```
# list is declared at global scope
mylist = [1,2,3]

def myfunction1():
    # function can call .append()
    mylist.append(4)
    mylist.append(5)

def myfunction2():
    # function can also call .remove()
    mylist.remove(4)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I forgot to mention the list needs to be reassignable throughout the program. I think I found a workaround to the problem anyways so thanks for the help!